# Asp.net core 3.1 API call returns 500 internet error only while returning data of child table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

> Error only appears when accessing the data from child table. If i remove the Employee table data, error disapear. Even for the department with no employee seems to give no errors.

```
    [HttpGet("bycompanyid/{companyid}")]
    public IEnumerable<Department> GetEmployeesByDepartId(long companyId)
    {
    List<Department> dep = _context.Department.Where(s => s.CompanyId == companyId).ToList();

            List<Employee> employees = _context.Employee.ToList();

            var result = (from rw in dep
                          select new Department
                          {
                              DepId = rw.DepId ,
                              Name = rw.Name,
                              Employee = (from employee in employees
                                                 where employee.DepId  == Convert.ToInt32(rw.DepId)
                                                 select employee).ToList(),
                          }).ToList();

            return result;
}
```

Comment: 500 oftentimes means, there is an exception thrown. Add some try catch to your server side action and check if that's the case here

Comment: Can you show us the error message, and the structure of your Department and Employee model?

Comment: Try catch doesn't pick anything

Comment: Try remove the try catch block to see the exception.